# How to use multiple routes files in mean.io

Tags: routes, mean-stack, mean.io

What's the "proper" way (if there is one) to use multiple routes files within mean.io to route requests?

I want to use multiple files for organization sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to the mean.io developers.  In the latest mean.io (as of posting this [2/11/15]), you MUST remove the `app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');` line from packages/system/app.js and add it to `packages/custom/yourPackageName/app.js`.  Otherwise the system one will persist.

To answer the question...  you cannot have multiple routes files it seems.

However, the mean.io developers (on gitter) were trying to make changes to allow for overriding the views, that way you don't have to remove the line from `server/views`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by altering the custom package register, which can be found at app.js in package/custom/CustomPackage/app.js file

From

```
CustomPackage.register(function(app, auth, database) {
```

to

```
CustomPackage.register(function(system, app, auth, database) {
app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
```

You don't need to touch system directory's code. Hope it will be helpful.